# Avoiding data copying during a RabbitMQ BasicPublish

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a requirement to use RabbitMQ to send messages in a Java program.  These messages contain 2 fields - A single byte identifier and many bytes of data.  Since the method basicPublish takes a byte[] as the message body I am forced to copy these 2 parameters into a single array.  And then on the receive side, I have to copy again to unwrap this.  Is there any way to do this without the copies?

Comment: Done.  Now do you have anything constructive concerning the question?

Comment: Why would you have to copy again on the receiver side? Why can't you just skip over the first identifier byte and then interpret the remaining data bytes in-place?

Comment: If you can show me how to skip the first byte in a java byte[] and use the remaining bytes as a byte[] without copying I would be grateful.  In c++ I would just use a pointer to byte+1 and pass that around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the single byte is an identifier, it can be considered as a meta information of the message: therefore I suggest you store it in a [header](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v2.6.1/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-2.6.1/com/rabbitmq/client/AMQP.BasicProperties.html#getHeaders%28%29) of the message and not in the payload. The payload would then only contain your data.

Comment: I have been searching for a place other than the payload to put this information, and this looks promising.  However, I am concerned with the fact that all of the sets are deprecated.  Are they only allowing a complete constructor now?

Comment: It seems like it: see the 3rd code sample here http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#publishing

Comment: After further digging the proper way to do this is by using AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder.